# Join columns according on value in first column but without having the column appearing twice

Tags: bash, join, merge, header-files

I have 3 space-separated files.

File 1 (*file1.txt*):

```
FID IID SEX PHENOTYPE KIR2DL5 KIR2DS5 
A1 A1 0 1 1 2
A2 A2 1 2 1 2
A3 A3 0 1 1 1
```

File 2 (*file2.txt*):

```
FID Bw4
A1 2
A2 1
A3 1
```

File 3 (*file3.txt*):

```
FID IID INFO
A1 A1 0.4
A2 A2 0.6
A3 A3 0.2
```

I want to merge the 3 files in a single file if the value in FID column is the same between the 3 files, in order to have:

```
FID IID SEX PHENOTYPE KIR2DL5 KIR2DS5 Bw4 INFO
A1 A1 0 1 1 2 2 0.4
A2 A2 1 2 1 2 1 0.6
A3 A3 0 1 1 1 1 0.2
```

I know that I can merge the files using the following command:

```
join file1.txt file2.txt | join - file3.txt > final.txt
```

But by using this command, it adds also the IID column from File 3, appearing thereby twice, like this:

```
FID IID SEX PHENOTYPE KIR2DL5 KIR2DS5 Bw4 IID INFO
A1 A1 0 1 1 2 2 A1 0.4
A2 A2 1 2 1 2 1 A1 0.6
A3 A3 0 1 1 1 1 A1 0.2
```

Is there a way to join the 3 files without having this column twice?

Important information:

- Not all FIDs are in common between the 3 files.
- The number of columns present in File 1 can change

Comment: Is the number of columns in file3 static? If yes, you can remove the second column of file3 (see `man colrm`). Using bash [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html): `join file1.txt file2.txt | join - <(colrm 2 < file3.txt)`

Comment: "I know that I can merge the files using awk like this:" ?? No awk code shown ;-) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt | awk '{ if ( $1==$7 && $1==$9) print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $5 "\t" $6 "\t" $8 "\t" $11}'
```

Explanation-

paste puts the files one after the other.

awk '{ if () }' checks for the condition to be true.

Rest is just cosmetics.

Comment: This also does not work if the number of columns in file1 changes.

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
join file1.txt file2.txt | join - file3.txt  | awk -v OFS=' ' 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if ($i=="IID"){n=i-1;m=NF-(i==NF)}} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1+(i==n))printf "%s%s",$i,i==m?ORS:OFS}' | column -t
```

this is your code;

```
join file1.txt file2.txt | join - file3.txt
```

To pretty formatting;

```
column -t
```

to delete IID column with awk;

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if ($i=="IID"){n=i-1;m=NF-(i==NF)}} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1+(i==n))printf "%s%s",$i,i==m?ORS:OFS}'
```

ex:

```
user@user-host:/tmp/1$ join file1.txt file2.txt | join - file3.txt  | awk -v OFS=' ' 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if ($i=="IID"){n=i-1;m=NF-(i==NF)}} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1+(i==n))printf "%s%s",$i,i==m?ORS:OFS}' | column -t
FID  IID  SEX  PHENOTYPE  KIR2DL5  KIR2DS5  Bw4  INFO
A1   A1   0    1          1        2        2    0.4
A2   A2   1    2          1        2        1    0.6
A3   A3   0    1          1        1        1    0.2
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the number of columns changed in file1. Then, it wouldn't be the 8th column anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut` and process substitution to remove the second column of file 3 before joining:

```
$ join file1.txt file2.txt | join - <(cut --complement -d ' ' -f 2 file3.txt)
FID IID SEX PHENOTYPE KIR2DL5 KIR2DS5 Bw4 INFO
A1 A1 0 1 1 2 2 0.4
A2 A2 1 2 1 2 1 0.6
A3 A3 0 1 1 1 1 0.2
```

`--complement` is a GNU extension. If you can't use it, the alternative is

```
join file1.txt file2.txt | join - <(cut -d ' ' -f 1,3 file3.txt)
```